# Innodb Table doesn't exist или катастрофа после отключения электропитания

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, innodb

Есть сервер, ubuntu xerus, на нем до сих пор безбедно крутилась maridb 10.1.19. Внезапно после отключения электропитания mysql перестал коннектиться к базам. Базы в Innobd. Есть все: frm и ibd файлы в папках с названиями баз, есть ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile2. После указания innodb_force_recovery=1 мускул поднялся, но при обращении к таблице (любой) базы (любой) отвечает мол table doesn't exist. Дамп снять невозможно, ругается, таблиц же типа не существует, mysqlcheck плюется тем же.

Опробовал [инструкцию](http://diff.org.ua/archives/2835) (и не одну), но после удаления tablespace и копирования ibd на уровне файловой системы бд плюется все тем же table doesn't exist. Т.е. он даже не пишет про несовпадение id, он просто таблиц не видит. При том при всем show tables все таблицы показывает. Drop сделать нельзя - таблиц же как бы нету, а create table в этой же бд вызывает ответ table already exist!

Уровни innodb_force_recovery вплоть до шестого никакого эффекта не оказывают.

Я в отчаянии. Даже тупо подсовывал все файлы новому серваку - разумеется, результат тот же. У меня даже почти на все базы структуры есть, но эта зараза плевать на это хотела - нет таблиц, и все тут!

Что делать? Боюсь, после такого пора с работы кружку забирать...

Comment: Жуткая история... Вся надежда на бэкап.

Comment: такая же ситуация, никто не нашёл решение? вопрос очень актуальный.

Answer (score 0):

ib_logfile хотите пересоздать или frm?

frm чинятся/проверяются через mysqlcheck

ib_logfileX  можно полностью удалить. только все сколько их есть и при запуске сервера они будут созданы все заново. только обязательно все, а не частично. раз они так повреждены, незавершённые транзакции в этих файлах всё рано потеряли ценность.

Конечно если речь идёт о восстановлении грубом.. просто ради спасения того, что осталось.